# Oracle Bind variable - query requested

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to create a bind parameter based results for my Oracle SQL Query.

like for example.

> Select * from emp where ename = :xyz;

it should ask me for the xyz value at runtime.

what should i do?

it keeps me givig error - Bind variable not declared...

please help...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running as a statement or as a script? One prompts you for bind values, but I don't have SQL Developer in front of me, and can't remember which!

Answer (score 5):

If you run your statement as a script (F5) then you'll get this in the 'script output' pane:

```
Bind Variable "xyz" is NOT DECLARED
```

If you run it as a statement (control-enter) instead then you're prompted for the bind value, and the result appears in the 'query result' pane.

If you do need to run as a script you can use a substitution variable in your query as AlexisSTDM showed, or you can keep it as a bind variable but declare it with the `variable` command and assign a value to it from a substitution variable - which means your actual query doesn't need to be hard-parsed for each new value:

```
variable xyz varchar2(1)
exec :xyz := '&abc';
select * from dual where dummy = :xyz;
```

When run as a script you'll be prompted for the *substitution* variable `abc`, and that value is then assigned to the bind variable `xyz`, which is used by the query. With a slightly more generic query and supplying the value `X` when prompted, the 'script output' pane shows:

```
old:exec :xyz := '&abc'
new:exec :xyz := 'X'
anonymous block completed
DUMMY
-----
X
```

You can add `set verify off` to hide the old/new lines, and can `set feedback off` before the `exec` to hide the `anonymous block completed` line, optionally turning it back on afterwards if you want feedback from your real queries. You can set a fixed value with `exec` if you prefer, but as you asked for prompts that isn't really relevant in this case; and if you have multiple bind values in the script, you can set them all from an anonymous PL/SQL block instead of using the `exec` shortcut multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using bind variable in procedures, you can use the bind variable in the following manner

Create your query as dynamic means stored in local variable 
for eg.

`create procedure PROC ( output_result out SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
l_query varchar2(1000) := Null;
begin 
l_query := 'Select * from emp where ename = :xyz';
OPEN output_result 
FOR l_query using xyz;
 End PROC ;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the escape character, in my case is &.

it would be

```
SELECT * from emp where ename = &xyz;
```

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Be sure you have executed: set escape off

Comment: You're changing from bind variables to substitution variables, which won't have the same benefits in SQL reuse (reduced hard parsing etc.); not really an issue here but not what the question was asking for? Why `set escape off` - there is no escaping here?